# how to debug in pycharm with command before python *.py?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am trying to debug the code in corporate server, however, I need to get permission by using a sepcific command(make it short, I'll call it `p`). How could I debug in pycharm with a start command

```
p python main.py
```

I tried to edit configuration, but neither parameters nor interpreter options worked as I expected. Are there any settings can modify the command to start python?

The ability of showing value of variable using `pdb` just not satisfy my requirements.

Comment: Not sure if this would work but you may try making `p python` a batch file/shell script and adding that script to PyCharm as a new Python interpreter.

Comment: I tried but I just don't know how to run a batch file/shell script while using debug mode. But I think this is a good idea, I'll try it again.

Comment: What I meant was to use the batch file as the python interpreter for your project, using the Add Python Intepreter menu.

Comment: oh, I get your point! thanks a lot. I am tryng now.

Comment: It can't connect to the pycharm debugger with the batch file as python interpreter, what a pity.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. Are you passing all arguments to the actual python interpreter? What is your operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on macOS 11. Since I don't know what `p` in your question is, I used the `time` command for testing:

Created a shell script named `/var/tmp/python` and made it an executable (`chmod +x /var/tmp/python`):

```
#!/bin/sh
time /usr/bin/python3 "$@"
```

The `"$@"` is used to pass all command line arguments passed to `/var/tmp/python` to the actual `/usr/bin/python3`.

Then I [added a new System Interpreter in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html) and picked `/var/tmp/python` as the executable.

When I debug my "Hello world" application this is the output:

```
/var/tmp/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 53332 --file "/var/tmp/hello_world.py"
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.5457.59)
Hello, world!

real    0m3.091s
user    0m0.292s
sys 0m0.078s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

as you can see in addition to executing/debugging the application it also printed the total time passed.

Comment: I want to run a .py code on the remote server, so I can not select "System Interpreter" as it seems to select only local interpreter. When I add a ssh interpreter, the stderr is "Could not obtain a remote socket from output"

Comment: oh! I wanted to figure out why it can not work with ssh configuration. And I reconfigured the ssh interpreter. It now worked, thanks a lot! Hope one day to be as proficient as you in python.